# Compare two dates using datepicker in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, comparison, redux-form

i have a DateInput component which i use in my redux form:

```
const MyDatePicker = ({ input, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
    <DatePicker
      {...input} dateFormat="DD-MM-YYYY"
      selected={input.value ? moment(input.value, 'DD-MM-YYYY') : null}
    />
    {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
  </div>
);
```

How to compare two dates which are produced by this component? I'm trying the isAfter function from moment.js but it didnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is unrelated to `redux-form`. It's just a general date comparison question. Moment can do it for you. You just need to figure out how.

```
const withinAYear = moment(start).add(1, 'year').isAfter(moment(end))
```

Comment: I was forgetting to add moment to the second argument. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

To compare two date objects you can convert you dates into Unix timestamp. Unix timestamp it's a number of seconds(milliseconds) from 1 january 1970. You will have two int and you can simply compare them.

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/

Comment: Thanks for your response Andrew! But i have a more complex task. I must validate that the difference should be max a year between the two dates